# R- How to loop a list of IDs contained in a data frame through an API URL?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, api, loops

I am using an API to receive some data from a website. The code for this is set up as follows:

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
url <- "https://api.WEBSITE.com/api/v1/ID"

response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers('API_KEY'), content_type("application/octet-stream"), accept("application/json"))

Data = fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content)
```

The output is a dataframe with 27 columns and one row of data for the respective ID.

I also have a dataframe with a list of IDs that can be individually plugged at the end of the url in the code above (where it says "ID") to retrieve data on each individual name in the list. Instead of plugging in every name individually and retrieving the data, I would like to loop through the data frame and plug in each ID automatically and generate a dataframe as output that contains all the data for each individual ID.

How do I set up a loop for the ID in the url and get all the output in one dataframe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a function to retrieve the data for a single id.  The function should take the id value as its first/only parameter.  Suppose this function is `myFun` and the data frame containing the IDs is called `df` and the column containing the ids is `id`.  Then `lapply(df$id, myFun)` will return a list of data frames containing the required information.  You can use `rbind` (base R) or `bind_rows` (tidyverse) to combine the list of data frames into a single data frame.

Comment: See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824897/ways-to-create-loop-analyse-multiple-images-using-azure-computer-vision-in-r/72826071#72826071).

Comment: Thank you! Still a beginner with R, would it be possible to write out the code? I tried to adapt it as follows:

Comment: urlfunction <- function(id) {
  url <- paste0("https://api.WEBSITE.com/api/v1/ID", id)
  response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers('API_KEY'), content_type("application/octet-stream"), accept("application/json"))
  Data = fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
  return(Data)
}

file_path <- "https://api.WEBSITE.com/api/v1/"
files <- list.files(path = file_path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
listOfDataFrames <- lapply(files, urlfunction)
allInOneDataframe <- lapply(files, urlfunction) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()

Answer (score 0):

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
require(tidyverse)

get_data <- function(id) {
  
  url <- paste0("https://api.WEBSITE.com/api/v1/", id)
  response <- VERB("GET", url, add_headers('API_KEY'), content_type("application/octet-stream"), accept("application/json"))
  Data = fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content)
                  
  return(Data)
}  

map_dfr(dataframe$IDs, get_data) # Replace the dataframe$IDs with the a vector of IDs or a colulm from a dataframe with IDs
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the error "Error in vctrs::data_frame(!!!.x, .name_repair = "minimal") :" appears - any idea why that might happen?

Comment: The full error says: Error in `vctrs::data_frame()`:
! Can't recycle `status` (size 3) to match `data` (size 16).
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map_dfr(IDs, get_data)
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
 3. dplyr:::map(...)
 4. base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 5. dplyr FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 6. vctrs::data_frame(!!!.x, .name_repair = "minimal")

Comment: I wish I had a real API link to draft a solution with, this is simply just a wild guess

Comment: The API link is https://api.tokeninsight.com/api/v1/coins/ but unfortunately I can't share the API key...